# How do I change onclick attributes in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have HTML that displays a button and a paragraph. When you click on the paragraph, it indicates whether the paragraph has been clicked on an odd or even amount of times. I'm trying to get the button to expand the paragraph to include a count of how many times the paragraph has been clicked, and revert back to it's original text when the button is clicked again. For some reason, I don't think my button properly communicates with the paragraph. Here's my code:

```
 var doClickCount = false;
 var clickCounter = 0 
 function toggleParagraphCounter(event) {
     var clickMeEvenTimes = true;
     doClickCount = true;
     if (doClickCount === true) {
        function clickMe() {  
      var para1 = document.getElementById("para1");
      if (clickMeEvenTimes) {
        clickCounter += 1; 
        para1.style = "color:green";
        para1.innerHTML = "Click this paragraph." +
        " It has been clicked an odd number of times.\
        Clicked" + clickCounter + "times with counting enabled." ;
      }
      else {  
        clickCounter += 1;
        para1.style = "font-size:0.9em";
        para1.innerHTML = "Click this paragraph." +
        " It has been clicked an even number of times.\
        Clicked" + clickCounter + "times with counting enabled.";
      }    
      clickMeEvenTimes = !clickMeEvenTimes;
  }
 }  else {
    function clickMe() {  
      var para1 = document.getElementById("para1");
      if (clickMeEvenTimes) {       
        para1.style = "color:green";
        para1.innerHTML = "Click this paragraph." +
        " It has been clicked an odd number of times.";
      }
      else {     
        para1.style = "font-size:0.9em";
        para1.innerHTML = "Click this paragraph." +
        " It has been clicked an even number of times.";
      }    
      clickMeEvenTimes = !clickMeEvenTimes;
  }
 }

 }
```

What else could I do to try and solve this?

Comment: Your HTML would be useful to understand the problem.

Comment: How to solve problem 101: First create a live example. You can build that in plunker and share with us.

Comment: a `function` construction inside  `else` is basically wrongdoing - also, not showing how you call `clickMe` and some HTML will most likely let you wait long (really, really long) for any answer.

Comment: Hey sorry everyone, the function clickMe is called by clicking the paragraph that displays the text. I don't know how to use plunker and I've never heard of it.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the clickMe function twice, below I have reformatted your code.

```
 var doClickCount = false;
 var clickCounter = 0 
 function toggleParagraphCounter(event) {

 var clickMeEvenTimes = true;
 doClickCount = true;

 if (doClickCount === true) {

 }  else {

 }
}
function clickMe() {  
  var para1 = document.getElementById("para1");
  if (clickMeEvenTimes) {       
    para1.style = "color:green";
    para1.innerHTML = "Click this paragraph." +
    " It has been clicked an odd number of times.";
  }
  else {     
    para1.style = "font-size:0.9em";
    para1.innerHTML = "Click this paragraph." +
    " It has been clicked an even number of times.";
  }    
  clickMeEvenTimes = !clickMeEvenTimes;
}
function clickMe() {  
  var para1 = document.getElementById("para1");
  if (clickMeEvenTimes) {
    clickCounter += 1; 
    para1.style = "color:green";
    para1.innerHTML = "Click this paragraph." +
    " It has been clicked an odd number of times.\
    Clicked" + clickCounter + "times with counting enabled." ;
  }
  else {  
    clickCounter += 1;
    para1.style = "font-size:0.9em";
    para1.innerHTML = "Click this paragraph." +
    " It has been clicked an even number of times.\
    Clicked" + clickCounter + "times with counting enabled.";
  }    
  clickMeEvenTimes = !clickMeEvenTimes;
```

}

Comment: What I'm trying to do is change the clickMe function, depending on whether or not the button has been clicked. clickMe is the function that determines what the paragraph does when I click it.

Comment: It is generally not a good plan to redefine a function.  If you want to be fancy about it you can create a new function, by returning a new function from a base function, but this is probably too complex for the problem you are solving.  Just create two functions.  Also by creating two functions it will be clear to you what the differences are and then you could go from there.  Another approach is to pass an argument to the function which causes it to behave differently.

Answer (score 0):

Hey so here's the code that worked:

```
 var doClickCount = false;
 var clickCounter = 0 

 function countPar1 () { 
      var para1 = document.getElementById("para1");
      if (clickMeEvenTimes) {
        clickCounter += 1; 
        para1.style = "color:green";
        para1.innerHTML = "Click this paragraph." +
        " It has been clicked an odd number of times.\
        Clicked " + clickCounter + " times with counting enabled." ;
      }
      else {  
        clickCounter += 1;
        para1.style = "font-size:0.9em";
        para1.innerHTML = "Click this paragraph." +
        " It has been clicked an even number of times.\
        Clicked " + clickCounter + " times with counting enabled.";
      }    
      clickMeEvenTimes = !clickMeEvenTimes;
 }

 function toggleParagraphCounter(event) {
 doClickCount =! doClickCount;
     if (doClickCount) {
document.getElementById("para1").onclick = function() {
    countPar1();
};       
 }  else {
 document.getElementById("para1").onclick = function() {
     clickMe();
   };

    }
 }
```